# change android dialer by intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Want to implement own `dialer` `activity`, but don't know how to show `chooser`, where user can choose my app as `dialer`. Found billions link how to catch calls or open `chooser` like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211795/make-call-in-android-application-using-default-call-application)

But this not fits to me. Need only to show chooser dialer dialog without make call after choose. Just only choose default dialer. Is it real? Will be glad any link or proposals.

Comment: Is [`Intent.ACTION_DIAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe, I dont know. Want, that user taps on setting item "set this app as default dialer". Then will open chooser dialog, where will be dialer apps. User choose some app, and chosen app will be dialer default app. Not like by link above, when after choice will be call ) Only changing default dialer app) I didnt find  it by google....

Comment: See this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587026/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-the-android-default-dialer-selection

Comment: Kiran Kumar, this link doesnt have answer (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this piece of code in your manifest file to choose the user your application as a dialer

```
<activity
android:name="com.sample.MyDailer"
android:label="@string/mycall" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I added it earlier. Thanks.  But my question, how to trigger chooser dialog, where user can choose com.sample.MyDailer  as default? ((

Comment: have you seen this link bro? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587026/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-the-android-default-dialer-selection

Comment: Yes, but didn't find the code how to trigger showed dialog.

Comment: for you plus one @KiranKumar