# Android add calling option

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, phone-call

How can i add my own application as call option (like Whatsapp, Viber)?
[image]

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587026/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-the-android-default-dialer-selection)

Another question (similar) doesn't solve my issue, my app doesn't show in the options in contact details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add my application to the android default Dialer selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587026/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-the-android-default-dialer-selection)

Answer (score 0):

1. to do that you need to define intent filter for you app in manifest file
2. add Call Phone Permission

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />                
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I suggest that i need something like AbstractAccountAuthenticator and AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.
But i don't know how to add my own option to all contacts.